# Kerberos auth with smartcard

Tags: kerberos, smartcard

I've got a fresh install of Fedora 34 installed and I'm trying to configure kinit to get kerberos tickets using my smartcard. I dont want to join the domain (which is Windows AD).

I've been successful at configuring it to allow me to login with a password, but cannot get it to work with my smartcard. When i try, it prompts me for my pin, then prompts me for my password.

pkcs15-tool lists the certificates from the smart card, it does have multiple certs on it. I'm not sure if i have the correct one selected in my krb5.conf file (not really sure what to look for).

I've copied the PEM certs from the domain controller to /etc/ssl/certs/root, and the CA used from the smartcard. I've also copied the same certs to /etc/pki/nssdb using certutil

Here is my krb5.conf file

```
[libdefaults]
    pkinit_anchors = DIR:/etc/ssl/certs/root/
    pkinit_pool = DIR:/etc/ssl/certs/sub/
    #pkinit_cert_match = || <EKU>msScLogin,<KU>digitalSignature
    #pkinit_eku_checking = kpServerAuth
    pkinit_kdc_hostname = DC.DOMAIN.COM
    pkinit_identities = PKCS11:opensc-pkcs11.so:slotid=0:certid=01
    default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
    default_realm = DC.DOMAIN.COM
    default_tgs_enctypes = arcfour-hmac-md5 des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
    default_tkt_enctypes = arcfour-hmac-md5 des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5

[realms]
  DC.DOMAIN.COM = {
    kdc = DC.DOMAIN.COM:88
    admin_server = DC.DOMAIN.COM
    default_domain = DC.DOMAIN.COM
}

[domain_realm]
# .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
# example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
.dc.domain.com = DC.DOMAIN.COM
```

The command i'm using to get the ticket

```
kinit -X 509_user_identity='PKCS11:opensc-pkcs11.so' username@DC.DOMAIN.COM
```

If i take out the -X option i can login with my password. What am i missing?

Edit - Also added the certs to /etc/pki/nssdb
Edit 2 - I'm pretty sure i'm selecting the correct certificate. I've also seen online many tutorials saying to run

```
modutil -add "OpenSC PKCS #11 Module" -libfile opensc-pkcs11.so -dbdir /etc/pki/nssdb
```

But when i do i get this error

```
ERROR: Failed to add module "OpenSC PKCS #11 Module". Probable cause : "Unknown PKCS #11 error.
```